# Varnish waits for the complete page load before sending response to browser

Tags: varnish

I've setup varnish to sit in front of a tomcat server. What I've noticed is that Varnish seems to wait for the complete page to load (all css, js, etc) before it sends any response to the browser.

This causes a huge lag before the user sees anything. If I bypass Varnish and go directly to the site, it responds immediately.

While the total page load time might be similar, the perception is that the site is slow.

Has anyone faced this?

Answer (score 2):

Unless you have JS and CSS inline in your HTML, the behavior you describe is simply technically impossible.
Your browser will need to receive and parse the HTML to extract `<script>` and `<link>` tags and send separate HTTP requests; even if they get to the same Varnish server, it will have no idea they are part of the same "page".

Try changing the HTML to load static (JS, CSS and images) from a different hostname that doesn't go to Varnish; that should make things easier to debug.
You could get the same result by using a command-line HTTP client, e.g. `curl`.
If you still see the same slow performance in this scenario, look at the Varnish logs, it will likely give you quite a few ideas for more stuff to check. Feel free to add that as a comment, that way we'll be able to help you better.

Answer (score 0):

With *the complete page to load (all css, js, etc)* you mean only embedded js and css resources, am I right? Varnish will buffer (and hopefully store) a response as a whole, before sending it to the client. If your back-end sends a response incrementally (e.g. chunked), a non-cached page might appear slower because it's only delivered by varnish after the back-end has sent its last piece.

If this is a problem, change the technical design of your application. Make sure most requests can be served from cache (these pages will be really fast) and externalize js & css resources (browser cache avoids doing requests at all). If there's only a small portion of your page that's slow and badly cacheable, load it asynchronously (e.g. Ajax).

There's also the concept of incremental rendering (a browser re-rendering pages as more resources become available), but I don't see how Varnish would change this behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I think you were getting confused by varnish's response buffering. Let's say the fastest your backend can respond with a 100k page for a given request is 10 seconds, sending 10k each second. Without varnish in your stack, the client connection gets tunneled directly to the back end, and the browser starts receiving data in 1 second (the first 10k, and starts to parse, render, follow `<link>` tags, etc).

With varnish in your stack, it waits for the back end to send the entire page before sending the first byte to the client. So the client has to wait 10 seconds until it can start rendering the page, following `<link>` tags, etc. Believe it or not, this is a good thing for two main reasons. One, if that response is cacheable, the next client won't have to wait 10 seconds for the back end to generate the response, varnish will serve it quite quickly (ms, not s). If your hit rate is high, which you should optimize for, the initial cost of having to wait for the first byte of the response pays many dividends in future cache hits. Two, let's say a mobile phone on a spotty cell signal requests that same 100k page, but it can't download the page as fast as the backend can generate it, it needs a full minute to receive the 100k page. With varnish in place, apache doesn't have to waste a connection and thread for an entire minute (mostly idle, mind you) while it slowly transmits the data to the client. It sends the data as fast as it can to varnish, and then moves on to the next request while varnish sends the data slowly to the client.

For requests that are known not to be cacheable, you can configure varnish via VCL, if you desire, to `return (pipe)` which will result in no response buffering. It will send data directly from your back end to the client as soon as it receives it. But in the default.vcl pipe is not used.